# Code First Migrations: Annotate whole database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am using the new EF 6.1 feature [Code First Annotations](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20First%20Annotations) which allow you to annotate tables or columns and then influence the SQL that is being produced during migration based on those annotations.

I find this is to be a very useful feature, because it saves me the trouble of manually altering the migration every time I need adjustments to the migrations code scaffolded by EF.

For example, I use it to annotate tables for history tracking:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasTableAnnotation("HistoryTracking", true);
```

I then set a custom SqlGenerator that inherits from `SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator` and generate additional SQL statements that enable history tracking for tables with this annotation set.

Now my question:

**Is it possible to apply this kind of Code First Annotations (or something similar) to the whole database?**

I would like to set a simple flag/annotation on the modelbuilder for the database that works in a similar fashion like the table/column annotations and allows me to generate more complex statements based on this flag.

Something like:

modelBuilder.Database.HasDatabaseAnnotation("HistoryTracking", true);

And in my custom SqlGenerator I would then check this annotation and generate a bunch of SQL Statements that disable/enable HistoryTracking for the whole database.

Is there a way to set something like this on the modelbuilder and check for it in the `SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator`?